# error codigo Python get() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

soy nuevo en el tema de programación de tkinter en python y estoy intentando hacer un programa simple.
El problema es que me sale el mismo error todo el rato:
Lo que quiero hacer es que el código, al colocar un dato en la variable "plantatexto" y luego darle al boton "enviar" guarde estos datos en "botonplanta1", asi, en el momento de presionar el "botonplanta1", se vuelva a escribir el dato en "plantatexto".
Este es el código:

```
from tkinter import *
def enviar():
  boton.get(boton)
def planta1():
  boton.set(boton)
r=Tk()

boton=StringVar()

plantatexto=Entry(r,textvariable=boton)
plantatexto.pack()
botonenviar=Button(r,text="ENVIAR",command=enviar,width=20,heigh=2)
botonenviar.pack()
botonplanta1=Button(r,text="Planta n°1",command=planta1,width=20,heigh=1)
botonplanta1.pack()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error es muy claro al respecto del problema:

> get() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

---

> get() toma un argumento posicional pero dos fueron dados.

El método `StringVar.get` solo recibe, como cualquier método de instancia, una referencia a la propia instancia de la clase como primer argumento (`self`). **Este argumento ya se pasa automáticamente** al llamarlo de la forma `instancia.metodo()`, por lo que no es `boton.get(boton)`, sino `boton.get()`

Además tienes otros dos errores:

- No llamas, al menos en el código que muestras, al ciclo de eventos o principal de la aplicación. `r.mainloop()`. Sin él, este código solo funcionará si se ejecuta bajo el intérprete interactivo del IDLE, dado que está escrito en Tkinter y usa su propio mainloop para ejecutar tu aplicación.
- La línea `boton.set(boton)` no tiene sentido, estás intentando asignar a `boton` como texto la propia instancia de `boton`, en todo caso puedes hacer `boton.set(boton.get())`, lo cualq tampoco tiene sentido porque asigna a la variable el valor que ya tiene... Además, en el momento que modifique el `Entry`, la `StringVar` cambiará su valor, por lo que no tiene sentido usarla para almacenar el valor en el momento de llamar a `enviar`. Es más, tampoco puedes  hacer que "...guarde estos datos en `botonplanta1`" como tal, no puedes asignar un valor a un botón, ni siquiera tiene el método `set` definido. Podrías crear un nuevo atributo de instancia para el botón y almacenar en él el texto en todo caso:

  ```
  def enviar():
      botonplanta1.valor = boton.get()

  def planta1():
      boton.set(botonplanta1.valor)

  botonplanta1=Button(r, ...)
  botonplanta1.valor = ""
  ```

  Aún así, lo más lógico sería usar otra `StringVar` o una lista de Python si vas a usar muchas para almacenar el valor asociado al botón/planta.

Aparte de estos errores, dos cosas que aún no siendo errores, deberías tener en cuenta:

- No uses `from modulo import *` (wildcard) a no ser que tengas muy claro que hace y que esté justificado su uso (solapamiento explícito del espacio de nombres actual por el del módulo importado por ejemplo). En general **es una mala práctica**, dificulta la legibilidad del código, puebla el espacio de nombres actual sin necesidad y lo peor de todo es que propicia el solapamiento de nombres de forma inadvertida pudiendo provocar errores o comportamientos inesperados. En tkinter, la forma aceptada generalmente de importar es `import tkinter as tk`, también sería válido aunque menos práctico `from Tkinter import Button, Entry, StringVar, Tk`. Vas a ver `from modulo import *` en muchos tutoriales que hay por ahí, empezando por la documentación no oficial sobre Tkinter que ofrece effbot, lo cual no deja de ser una muy mala práctica.
- Intenta usar siempre cuatro espacios para identar como marcan las [convenciones de estilo definidas en PEP 8](http://www.recursospython.com/pep8es.pdf). Aunque nadie te obliga a seguirlas, entre otras cosas proporcionan un estándar que facilitan la lectura y comprensión del código por otros programadores, parte esencial de la filosofía de Python.

Tu código podría quedar así:

```
import tkinter as tk



def enviar():
    valor = planta_entry_var.get()
    planta1_var.set(valor)

def planta1():
    valor = planta1_var.get()
    planta_entry_var.set(valor)

root = tk.Tk()

planta_entry_var = tk.StringVar()
planta1_var = tk.StringVar()

planta_entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=planta_entry_var)
planta_entry.pack()
boton_enviar = tk.Button(root, text="ENVIAR", command=enviar, width=20, heigh=2)
boton_enviar.pack()
boton_planta1 = tk.Button(root, text="Planta n°1", command=planta1, width=20, heigh=1)
boton_planta1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```